Socket.io in nodejs is connecting when i call localhost:8002 but not work when i call 192.168.2.10:8002 it doesnot connect
I am testing my changes on https://piehost.com/socketio-tester
My code is:

index.js:

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const sequelize = require("../configs/db-config");

const { initSocket } = require("../configs/socket-config");

// Import all routes here
const userRoutes = require("./user/user.routes");
const otpRoutes = require("./otp/otp.routes");
const coyoteRoutes = require("./coyote/coyote.routes");
const voucherRoutes = require("./voucher/voucher.routes");

require("./cronjobs/subscriptionExpiry");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

// APP SETUP
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Set up EJS as the view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views")); // Path to views directory

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Default route to display API documentation
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("api_documentation", {
    endpoints: [
      { method: "POST", path: "/api/v2/user/signup", description: "Registers a new user", params: ["fullName", "email", "password", "dob", "profilePic"] },
      { method: "POST", path: "/api/v2/user/signin", description: "Logs in a user and returns a JWT token", params: ["email", "password", "FCMToken"] },
      { method: "POST", path: "/api/v2/user/resetPassword", description: "Resets user password", params: ["email", "password"] },
      { method: "GET", path: "/api/v2/user/getFeed", description: "Fetches feed based on user location", params: ["latitude", "longitude", "radius"] },
      { method: "PUT", path: "/api/v2/user/editUser", description: "Edits a user's profile", params: ["userId", "profilePic", "updatedData"] },
      { method: "GET", path: "/api/v2/user/getReportsHistory", description: "Fetches user's report history", params: ["userId"] },
      { method: "GET", path: "/api/v2/user/getUsers", description: "Fetches users or a specific user", params: ["userId (optional)"] },
      { method: "POST", path: "/api/v2/user/addSubscription", description: "Adds a subscription for the user", params: ["userId", "voucherId", "paymentIntentId"] },
      { method: "POST", path: "/api/v2/otp", description: "Generates an OTP for the user", params: ["email"] },
      { method: "POST", path: "/api/v2/voucher/redeem", description: "Redeems a voucher for credits", params: ["voucherCode", "userId"] },
      { method: "DELETE", path: "/api/v2/user/account", description: "Deletes the user account", params: ["userId"] },
      
      // Add other relevant endpoints here based on your codebase
    ],
  });
});


// Use the routes here
app.use("/api/v2/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/v2/otp", otpRoutes);
app.use("/api/v2/coyote", coyoteRoutes);
app.use("/api/v2/voucher", voucherRoutes);

// Sequelize Connection with DB
sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database synchronized successfully");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
  });

initSocket(server);

server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));



and my socket-config.js is:

let io; // Declare io at a higher scope
const userService = require("../app/user/user.service");
const coyoteService = require("../app/coyote/coyote.service");


const initSocket = (server) => {
  io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*", // Adjust this as needed
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("New client connected");

    socket.on("updateUserLocation", async (locationPayload) => {
      try {
        let { userId, latitude, longitude, radius } =
          JSON.parse(locationPayload);

        if (!userId || !latitude || !longitude) {
          socket.emit(
            "socketError",
            JSON.stringify({
              message: "userId, latitude, longitude is required for join Room",
            })
          );
          return;
        }

        if (!radius) radius = 400;

        const userUpdated = await userService.editUserProfile(
          userId,
          { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
          null
        );
        if (!userUpdated.status)
          socket.emit(
            "updationError",
            JSON.stringify({ message: userUpdated.message })
          );

        const filterOptions = {
          latitude: latitude,
          longitude: longitude,
          radius: radius,
        };

        //now fetch the new feed
        const feedFetch = await coyoteService.findCoyotesWithinRadius(filterOptions);

        //now return the entity
        socket.emit(
          "locationUpdated",
          JSON.stringify({
            message: "location updated successfully",
            feed: feedFetch,
          })
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Room could not be joined");
        socket.emit(
          "socketError",
          JSON.stringify({
            message: error.message,
          })
        );
        return;
      }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Client disconnected");
    });
  });

  return io;
};

// Export a function that returns the initialized io instance
const getIoInstance = () => {
  if (!io) {
    throw new Error("Socket.io not initialized. Please call initSocket first.");
  }
  return io;
};

module.exports = {
  initSocket,
  getIoInstance,
};

I have tested all the things GPT has asked me to do but nothing works.

what are some of the things GPT has asked me to do? and as for testing my changes ... changes to what?

https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Adding all origins.
Allowing the hosts.
@Bravo

Adding all origins. to what? Allowing the hosts where? to do what?

Have you checked (netstat -l) what address it is listening on to make sure it isn't listening to only localhost (despite what is in your code)?  Have you checked if there is a host side firewall blocking you?

So here is the thing. I have a node.js based backend server on my local. I am trying to connect to the socket.io in my porject. It connects when i use http://localhost:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000
but when i write http://192.168.43.40:3000 it doesn't connect.
i am on mac. and this is really an issue for me as i want to use the ip. if i ping my local ip on terminal
PING 192.168.43.40 (192.168.43.40): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.43.40: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.43.40: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms
its the correct ip of my local pc.
